# regex single character between delimiter

Tags: regex

I am trying to [query the stackoverflow data in BigQuery.](https://medium.com/google-cloud/google-bigquery-public-datasets-now-include-stack-overflow-q-a-5a8a7e371b52) I would like to use the `REGEXP_CONTAINS` function to pull all questions with the `r` tag. The `tags` column is a pipe delimited field that contains all of the tags associated with each question. A sample of what that looks like is below:

[image]

I can't seem get a regex that works.

[I am almost there with `\|?(r)\|?`](https://regex101.com/r/o2DfFr/1). This will work for:

```
r
sql|r|python
c
vba|r
r|java
```

But it will also return things like:

```
ruby
angular|c|vba
```

...which I don't want.

I need to somehow have a regex that will pull `r` all alone *unless* it has a pipe on either side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
(?:^|\|)(r)(?:\||$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/o2DfFr/3)

**Details**

- `(?:^|\|)` - a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions) matching start of string or `|` char
- `(r)` - Group 1: `r`
- `(?:\||$)` - a non-capturing group matching  `|` char or end of string.

Comment: Thank you, this works and your explanation is very helpful. Thinking about this from a start of string OR pipe / pipe OR end of string is the cognitive jump which I couldn't make. Thanks!